# Python string as callable method

Tags: python, string, callable

I'm having a problem concatenating a string to a variable to create a method in my program (pythonista app). It goes something like this:

```
buttons = ''' Scan_View Show_View '''.split()

class OCRApp():

  def __init__(self):
      pass

  def scan_view_action(self, sender):
      scanview = ui.load_view('scanview.pyui')
      scanview.background_color = 'red'
      scanview.present()

  def show_view_action(self, sender):
      pass 

  def make_button(self, name, i):
      button = ui.Button(title=name)
      the_action = name + '_action'
      button.action = the_action()
      button.center = w / 2, (i * 60) + (button.height * 2)
      self.add_subview(button)
      return button
```

When I create a string on the variable `the_action` and call it on `button.action` I get an error:

```
TypeError: "str" object is not callable
```

How do I go about doing this correctly?

Comment: the_action = getattr(self, name + '_action')

Comment: @hsfzxjy thanks worked perfectly!